# How can I find more lockpicks?

Tags: the-division

There are tons of locked doors all around the city. I've found about two lockpicks so far, one was from a random enemy and I'm not sure where I found the other one. How can I acquire more lockpicks to open up the locked doors?

Comment: I feel like I've had three lockpicks for pretty much the whole game. It doesn't seem like opening doors actually consumes one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no definite way to get lock picks. It is purely luck of the draw through loot. Probably the best way to get them as of now is to farm low-level missions.

I'm in the same boat myself, and dug around a bit to find an answer. Hopefully they patch this in the future for a higher drop rate, or so they are craftable.

Comment: Having them be craftable would be nice... They seem like fairly uncommon loot so far (which I suppose kinda makes sense, how often do you come across actual lock picks in real life?).

Comment: What a strange design choice. I'll hold off on accepting this for now in the dim hopes there is some underlying logic, but you've earned my +1

Comment: Sounds fine by me! If I find anymore details down the line (I imagine that the developers will address it at some point) I'll be sure to update my answer.